# Excel VBA - Making a chess board

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a 10*10 chess board in excel starting from whichever cell I am on, using black and white color. Have tried the following code but need further help. Can some one please help me to run it with required changes.

```
Sub COLOR()

Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long

For I = 1 To 10
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    For J = 1 To 10
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    Next J
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: what does `required changes` even mean? .... you said nothing about what the code does when you run it  ....  you said nothing about any errors .... `i have a car, can you make the required changes to it?` ... see? ...  a pretty useless question.

Comment: single-step your code using the F8 key and watch the "selection" on the worksheet. you will see the problem

Answer (score 2):

I can never remember which corner has the dark colour and which has the light colour on a chess board but, if the following code does it back to front, just change `If (I + J) Mod 2 = 0 Then` to `If (I + J) Mod 2 <> 0 Then`:

```
Sub COLOR()

    Dim origin As Range
    Set origin = ActiveCell

    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long

    For I = 0 To 9
        For J = 0 To 9
            With origin.Offset(I, J).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic

                If (I + J) Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                Else
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                End If

                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Next J
    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Wonderful..thanks for the code.However I wonder for what the below  commands used as just using ".ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1" is giving the required results. .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic  .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0

Comment: @SNEHA I just copied those statements from your original code - why did **you** have them there??

Comment: sorry but I recorded a macros to make a chess board and used these statements from there, I still could not understand their utility. Still learning...

Comment: @SNEHA There are **lots** of different options that can be used when formatting cells - colour, pattern colour, pattern style, etc.  The macro recorder would have used the options necessary to give you what you asked for but if, for example, you know that your cell already is set to have a solid pattern, you won't need to set that option again and can leave it out of your code.